# casper js screenshot not working with svg masks

Tags: casperjs

I'm creating visualizations with d3 that use svg masks and I'm trying to get a screenshot using casper js. It usually works fine except it's not rendering the mask properly; it shows all of the layers rather than just the one being masked. This is the casper code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost:3000', function() {
    this.captureSelector('bicycles.png', 'svg');
});

casper.run();
```

Anybody else having issues with this?

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Do the SVGs render properly in other WebKit browsers? (Casper uses PhantomJS, which is webKit based)

Comment: Hi @GarethOwen, it renders fine in webkit browsers but when using casperjs and phantomjs the mask isn't rendering properly. Intriguing...

Comment: selector 'svg' should be a dom id. right? like '#svg'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help, but in my tests I always set the viewport size and then add a delay before running any other code. One reason for the delay is because we are using knockout and DOM elements have not been fully created by the time the 'start' function is called.

So your test would look like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost:3000', function () {
    casper.viewport(1024, 768);
});

casper.wait(1000); // Wait for knockout bindings and animations...

casper.then(function () {
    this.captureSelector('bicycles.png', 'svg');
});

casper.run();
```

Probably won't help you, but worth a try?

Comment: Thanks @GarethOwen, didn't quite work as the svg mask isn't rendering properly. This could be a bug within PhantomJS but I'm not entirely sure yet. Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer :)